# ¿Porque tengo un error en este script de Python?

Tags: python, lista, variables, algoritmos, condiciones

El script es el siguiente:

```
valor1=0
cuit=[]
num=[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

for x in range(11): 
    inuser= int(input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: "))
    cuit.append(inuser)
for x in range(10):
    aux1 = cuit[x]*num[x]
    valor1 = aux1+valor1
valor2= valor1%11
valor3= 11-valor2


if valor3==11:
    digitoV=0
if valor3==10:
    digitoV=9
else:
    digitoV=valor3
if digitoV==cuit[10]:
    print("Muchas gracias")
else:
    print("Revise el CUIT/CUIL ingresado")
```

La idea es que compruebe si el CUIT o CUIL ingresado es valido segun el algoritmo `modulo 11` y si! funciona, excepto cuando ingreso un CUIT con las siguientes caracteristicas `27-0nnnnnnn-0`  no lo toma como valido, resulta que haciendo pruebas me di cuenta de que al ingresar el CUIT con el que estoy probando la variable `valor3`  da el resultado de `11`  por lo cual se tendria que cumplir la siguiente sentencia que es:

```
if valor3==11:
    digitoV=0
```

Si esta sentencia se cumpliera entonces el script daria el mensaje `Muchas gracias` pero en cambio da `Revise el CUIT/CUIL ingresado` Lo cual me hace pensar que no se esta cumpliendo. Estuve realizando pruebas pero no logro entender porque no se ejecuta correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Habia un error en la forma de aplicar las sentencias. La correccion es la siguiente:

```
valor1=0
cuit=[]
num=[5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

for k in range(11): 
   inuser= int(input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: "))
   cuit.append(inuser)
for x in range(10):
   aux1 = cuit[x]*num[x]
   valor1 = aux1+valor1
valor2= valor1%11
valor3= 11-valor2

if valor3==11:
   digitoV=0
elif valor3==10:
   digitoV=9
else:
   digitoV=valor3
if digitoV==cuit[10]:
   print("Muchas gracias")
else:
   print("Revise el CUIT/CUIL ingresado")
```

Como se puede observar se modificaron las sentencias:

```
if valor3==11:
    digitoV=0
if valor3==10:
    digitoV=9
else:
    digitoV=valor3
```

Por:

```
if valor3==11:
   digitoV=0
elif valor3==10:
   digitoV=9
else:
   digitoV=valor3
```